# React - Calling function from another function does not work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function

I have a game programmed in React code that is divided in two sections: The first section defines if the game is easy or hard. The second section is the game itself

```
Function App() {
    return (
        <>
        <div><First/></div> 
        <div'><Second/></div>
        </>
    )
}

export default Main
```

On the first section, the user clicks on a button to define the level. That should have an impact on the second section. This is what I wrote.

First.js:

```
import React from 'react'
import { useState } from "react";
import '../paginas/ind.css'
import Second from './Second';


function First() {
    const [Difficulty,setdifficulty] = useState(1)


    function easy(e){ 
        setdifficulty(1)
        Second(1)
      }

    function hard(e){ 
        setdifficulty(2)
        Second(2)
      }  
    return (
        <>
        {Difficulty !== 1 ? <div onClick={easy}>Easy</div> :
        <div>Easy</div>} 
        {Difficulty !== 2 ?<div onClick={hard}>Medium</div>:
        <div>hard</div>}
        </>
    )
}

export default Izq
```

Second.js:

```
import React from 'react'
import '../paginas/ind.css'
import Difficulty from './First'
import First from './First '

function Second (Difficulty) {
console.log(Difficulty)
    return (
        <>
        {Difficulty === 1 ? <div>This game is going to be easy</div>:<div></div>}
        {Difficulty === 2 ? <div>This game is going to be hard</div>:<div></div>}
        </>
    )

}

export default Central
```

I don´t know why but when I click on "easy" or "hard" on the First script, nothing happens on the second. By using console.log(Difficulty) on Second.js I can know that there is a change happening in the value of the variable "Difficulty". But the condition "{Difficulty === 1 ? This game is going to be easy:}" assumes that its value is cero. I can´t find any sense in this. Please help me.

Thank you

Comment: You are not using your `Second` component anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You must first learn about the basic of react, how to pass around props and states correctly, usage of `context` api in react etc. I recommend you go through some tutorials first.

That being said, if you change the functions of your `App`, `First` and `Second` component like below, you will get the result. This is just the most simplest way of doing it.

```
function First() {
  const [Difficulty, setdifficulty] = useState(1);
  return (
    <>
      {Difficulty !== 1 ? (
        <div onClick={(e) => setdifficulty(1)}>Easy</div>
      ) : (
        <div>Easy</div>
      )}
      {Difficulty !== 2 ? (
        <div onClick={(e) => setdifficulty(2)}>Medium</div>
      ) : (
        <div>hard</div>
      )}
      <Second Difficulty={Difficulty} /> // You will have to import the second component into this page. And remove it from App
    </>
  );
}

function Second(props) {
  const { Difficulty } = props;
  return (
    <div>
      {Difficulty === 1 && <div>This game is going to be easy</div>}
      {Difficulty === 2 && <div>This game is going to be hard</div>}
    </div>
  );
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <First />
    </div>
  );
}
```